# Plot coordinates to a map in R and connect them by lines (= graph on a map)

Tags: r, graph, maps, overlay

I would like to create a map of Germany with R and place some points (with geo coordinates) on it. Then I want to connect some of the points with lines of different color and width. So I could also say, I want to build a graph with fixed position of the nodes over the picture of a map. The map is not really important (can be very coarse) and should not be google maps.

For example with the following code I get a coarse map of Germany:

```
    library(maps)
    map("world", regions="Germany")
```

How can I add points to this map and connect them?

EDIT: My data looks like this:

I have a data frame for the points to place on the map:

```
    Name  |  Latitude    |   Longitude
    ------+--------------+------------
    Point1|  50.110556   |   8.682222
    Point2|  52.516667   |   13.383333
    Point3|  48.137222   |   11.575556
```

And I have a data frame with the lines to draw between the points:

```
    Source | Target | color | width
    -------+--------+-------+-------
    Point1 | Point2 |  red  |   2   
    Point1 | Point3 | green |   5
```

Thank you! :)

Comment: Fundamentally you can do this using the `points` and `lines` functions. What does your data look like? You've not given us much to work with.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I added some information on my data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use functions like points and lines.

```
library(maps)
map("world", regions="Germany")
set.seed(10)
dfPoints <- data.frame(
  long = 10 + runif(10, -2, 2),
  lat = 50 + runif(10, -2, 2)
  )
points(x = dfPoints$long, y = dfPoints$lat, col = "red")
lines(x = dfPoints$long, y = dfPoints$lat, col = "blue")
```

You can also take a look at the ggmap package, based on ggplot2.

Comment: That looks already quite nice! Is it also possible to define the width of the lines?

Comment: Yep, it's the lwd argument. e.g.
lines(x = dfPoints$long, y = dfPoints$lat, col = "blue", lwd = 5)

Comment: Great! One last question: Is it also possible to zoom in the map? For example only to show the area around one defined coordinate with a defined zoom factor?

Comment: Read the help for the map function, it will tell you how to set the xlim and ylim parameters. The help for points and lines will also tell you how to style lines and points.